# Form submissions results in invalid byte sequence in utf-8 erro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I have form that has a good number of string fields. In some form submits, it results in `invalid byte sequence in utf-8` error.

The error occurs when i try to save the data like this:

```
@event = Event.new(params[:event])
@event.save
```

In my application.rb, I have these two lines for encoding.

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Am I missing anything? Please help.